# What monitoring system should I use for offline network

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios, service, containers

I'm part of a sysadmin\DevOps team for for an application. Currently today we have about 25 - 40 vms running as different parts of the application in micro services on the
openshift container platform, using also Jenkins, Nexus3, some relational and mongo DB's.

I'm looking into monitoring the servers and different linux services on them. First I found out about monit and part from it's single server monitoring ability using the web GUI it was pretty fast and simple to use.

Yet again I can't have that many different GUIs to look at to understand the network status. More recently I've encountered Nagios core and XI and currently in the process of deploying the (Nagios core) nrpe_3.2.1 agents on the different nodes in the network, yet because of dependency issues I'm leaning toward Nagios XI for ease of use and so it would "just work". I specifically want service monitoring and event handlers is case of service crash or status change to keep all running without requiring my attention. If I can get a validation on the existing or recommendation for something better (as well as hopefully free and open source) it'd be much appreciated. Thnx, Noam.

Comment: If monit works for you, you can use mmonit https://mmonit.com/ which aggregates the different monit client instances into a single GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s no reason not to use M/Monit for central status in this environment. The cost is absurdly low and it will plug into what you e already established.